# Windows 7 keyboard shortcut to make current window transparent?

Tags: windows-7, transparency

Is there a keyboard shortcut or some kind of setting to make the current window transparent?

I go back and forth between windows a lot. If I could just make the window I'm looking at transparent, it would be nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#Space:: ;Show windows under pointed-at.
    WinSet, Transparent, 25, A
return
#Space UP:: ;Restores window when you release the keys
    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
return
```

AutoHotKey can do it! No fancy glass effects, but the window goes transparent. That's on Windows Key and Space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in shortcut that comes to mind, only one that makes **all** windows transparent:

<kbd>Win</kbd> +

However this isn't very useful for your situation.

Take a look at **[TweakWindow](http://download.cnet.com/TweakWindow/3000-2072_4-10383265.html)**. It worked for me on Vista, not sure about 7. It has a useful "**Make it Ghost**" feature which not only makes the current window transparent, but also allows you to click through it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Phoshi, I use an AutoHotKey script that's a slightly modified version of [this](https://github.com/jvtrigueros/AutoHotkeyScripts/blob/master/Opacity/opacity.ahk).

It uses <kbd>Windows</kbd>+Mouse Wheel Up/Down to adjust transparency, and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+Mouse Middle/Wheel Button to toggle off, or on to a preset.  I find this control mechanism to be quite intuitive, allowing for rapid changes to window transparency as I work.

```
; Modified version of https://github.com/jvtrigueros/AutoHotkeyScripts/blob/master/Opacity/opacity.ahk

#WheelUp::  ; Increments transparency up by 3.375%
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
    WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if ! curtrans
        curtrans = 255
    newtrans := curtrans + 8

    WinSet, Transparent, %newtrans%, A
return

#WheelDown::  ; Increments transparency down by 3.375%
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
    WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if ! curtrans
        curtrans = 255
    newtrans := curtrans - 8
    if newtrans > 0
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, %newtrans%, A
    }
return

#MButton::  ; Reset Transparency Settings
    WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if curtrans
    {
       WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
       WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
    }
    else
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, 200, A
    }

return
```